# Can Bootstrap4 set a column without gutter?

Tags: bootstrap-4, gutter

I have a question about layout without gutter.
I know there is .no-gutters on .row, and it will apply on every columns in the row.

But I'd like to set only sidebar with no-gutter.
Is there any way to achive this?

Comment: You can just use `px-0` to remove left and right paddings? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/208690/

Comment: @DavidLiang that solves this issue. Thank you so much.